# Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties' and Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

[image: image taken on : lenove ideapadslim 5 os : Windows android studio chipmunk version]when I set compile sdk version to 31 error occurs it is not going even if undo that change

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove "new" in front of GradleException, and it will solved the problem. It should look like this.

**Step 1:**

```
throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

In some case, this is due to an invalid SDK configuration. you can solved it by going to:

**Step 2:** Project structure > Project Settings > Modules > Module SDK and switching from  or old SDK to Android api 31 platform.

**Step 3:** In last Go to File -> Invalidate Chache / Restart.

In few case, Need to include google maven repository to your project level build.gradle file if it is not there.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {                                    //add this section 
            url "https://maven.google.com"           
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}
```